# Is it possible to enable an SELinux boolean in a policy module?

Tags: selinux

`audit2allow` creates fine-grained policy modules, but often hints that an existing boolean represents a superset of a policy line. For example:

```
#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'domain_kernel_load_modules'
allow collectd_t kernel_t:system module_request;
```

Is it possible to **replace the `allow` line with a reference to the boolean** (in the policy module as opposed to `semanage boolean --modify --on domain_kernel_load_modules`)? I can't seem to find any reference to such a syntax.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enable a boolean, you don't have to create a module, so as far as I know, there is no syntax.

Instead you can run:

```
$ setsebool -P domain_kernel_load_modules on
```

While *-P* will make the change persistent.

Comment: I did say specifically "in the policy module, as opposed to [a shell command]"…

Comment: Ok so NO you can't. You can't set global booleans inside your SE Linux modules as its a total different thing.